# jquery simplemodal plugin: popup that scroll with the page

Tags: scroll, simplemodal, fixed, absolute

Is there a 'valid' solution for the dialog to scroll with the scrollbar instead of still being fixed from the center of the inner window bound ?

There is some situation where the user may have a too small resolution to contain the dialog, and in that case part of the dialog maybe hidden.
You may have a Ok or confirm button in the hidden part, and then the popup may not be closed, nor validated ! Blocking situation.

I tried to change a css into the code from fixed to absolute, and then the dialog scroll with the page: great! But... Meanwhile doing this, opening another popup, do not position it again centered into the layout. Maybe a solution is to recenter the dialog on each onOpen event.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog was written to be fixed and as such is not easily changeable.

You could change the position to absolute, but all of the IE hacks will force it to behave as fixed.

Comment: It is possible thus to disable the ie hack section in the code and it works fine also for ies.

Comment: since i have encounterd the same problem ( i pop up a flash game, which the controls for it are at the bottom, and also added a side tab to the modal with diffrent buttons ), i find your answer really not appropiate.

Comment: btw, to anyone interested, in SimpleModal 1.4.1, You can change the following line: `l.position = 'fixed';` to `l.position = 'absolute';` in the fixIE function. that will give the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

In SimpleModal 1.4.2 you can simply set fixed to false:

```
$('#myModal').modal({ fixed: false });
```

This worked for us on Chrome and IE all the way back to IE8. (We don't support IE7.)